# Add a delay duration variable to popup Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code that causes a popup to appear, then close and reappear. I need to try and set a random delay inbetween each message that pops up. So it would be a popup message, then a delay that I can set the time for, then the next popup message, then a delay, then next popup, and continuing on for as
many popups as I need. The two parts of the code are shown below...

```js
function showPopup(options) {
  var messages_array = options.messageText;
  var no_of_messages = messages_array.length;
  var pop_up_height = 400;
  var showDuration = 12000;
  var duration = 12000;
  var startInterval;
  var popupPosition = options.position;
  var popupCSS = "";
  if (popupPosition == "topleft") {
    popupCSS = "position:fixed;top:0;left:0;margin:0 auto;";
  }
  if (popupPosition == "topcenter") {
    popupCSS = "position:fixed;top:0;left:50%;margin:0 auto;";
  }
  if (popupPosition == "topright") {
    popupCSS = "position:fixed;top:0;right:0;margin:0 auto;";
  }
  if (popupPosition == "middleleft") {
    popupCSS = "position:fixed;top:50%;left:0;margin:0 auto;";
  }
  if (popupPosition == "middlecenter") {
    popupCSS = "position:fixed;top:50%;left:50%;margin:0 auto;";
  }
  if (popupPosition == "middleright") {
    popupCSS = "position:fixed;top:50%;right:0;margin:0 auto;";
  }
  if (popupPosition == "bottomleft") {
    popupCSS = "position:fixed;bottom:0;left:0;margin:0 auto;";
  }
  if (popupPosition == "bottomcenter") {
    popupCSS = "position:fixed;bottom:0;left:50%;margin:0 auto;";
  }
  if (popupPosition == "bottomright") {
    popupCSS = "position:fixed;bottom:0;right:0;margin:0 auto;";
  }

  var html_snippet = "<div id='popup' style='" + popupCSS + "'><div id='close' style='height:20px;width:100%;cursor:pointer;display:none;'><span style='color:#fff;float:right;top:0px;'>X</span></div>";
  jQuery("body").append(html_snippet);
  if (options.height) {
    pop_up_height = options.height;
    jQuery("#popup").css("height", options.height);
  }
  if (options.width) {
    jQuery("#popup").css("width", options.width);
  }
  if (options.showDuration) {
    showDuration = options.showDuration;
  }
  if (options.imageUrl) {
    jQuery("#popup").css("background-image", "url(" + options.imageUrl + ")");
  }
  if (options.messageText) {
    jQuery("#popup").append("<p style='margin:0 auto;text-align:center;paddin:10px;color:white;'></p>");
  }
  if (options.duration) {
    duration = options.duration;
  }
  $("#popup").hide();
  startInterval = setInterval(function() {
    jQuery("#popup >p").text(messages_array[[Math.floor(Math.random() * messages_array.length)]].Message);
    $("#close").css("display", "block");
    $("#popup").show();
    setTimeout(function() {
      jQuery("#popup>p").text('');
      $("#popup").hide();
    }, showDuration);
  }, duration);
  $("#close").click(function() {
    clearInterval(startInterval);
  });
}



jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  showPopup({
    height: 200, // height of popup
    width: 400, // width of popup
    imageUrl: "", // background image path for popup
    messageText: [{
      "Message": "message goes here"
    }, {
      "Message": "the next message goes here"
    }, {
      "Message": "another message"
    }], //  messages text shownon pop up 
    duration: 5000, // duration for next popup
    position: "middlecenter", // position for popup (topleft,topcenter,topright,middleleft,middlecenter,middleright,bottomleft,bottomcenter,bottomright;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>popup script</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js" integrity="sha256-iT6Q9iMJYuQiMWNd9lDyBUStIq/8PuOW33aOqmvFpqI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: looks like a good time to use `switch case`

Comment: looks like a good time to use CSS classes....

Comment: looks like a good time to format this code

Comment: So are you saying that either the duration or showDuration variables must be random?  I'm just trying to clarify what you mean when you say you want a delay you can set a time for and then you follow that up with other delays.  Is the first delay set and others random?

Comment: So what I mean is... The popup happens. Then closes. Now when it's closed I want to be able to set the amount of time isn't closed for. But I want to be able to set a different duration inbetween each popup. So not just add say 5seconds, but add different amounts of seconds inbetween each popup. So it would appear to be randomly popping up. Not just at the same pace. So pop up/popup disappears, now a 4 sec delay, then pop up/popup disappears, 8 sec delay, then pop up/popup disappears, 2 sec delay, then pop up/popup disappears, 20 sec delay. Does that it's the delay "inbetween each" that I need

Answer (score 0):

You would need to abandon `setInterval` as obviously that causes intervals of the same duration. Instead use `setTimeout` and wrap it in a function that you call again via a nested `setTimeout`.

Here is how the `setInterval` part of your code would be replaced:

```
var startInterval;
var i = 0;
(function loop() {
    $("#popup >p").text(messages_array[i].Message);
    i = (i + 1) % messages_array.length; // next index ...
    $("#close").css("display", "block");
    $("#popup").show();
    startInterval = setTimeout(function() {
        $("#popup>p").text('');
        $("#popup").hide();
        startInterval = setTimeout(loop, duration * (Math.random() * 1.5 + 0.5));
    }, showDuration);
})();
```

The actual pause between the popups is now set to a random duration between `duration/2` and `duration*2`. That way you can still influence it.

As to the rest of your code: try to avoid applying inline styles. Instead define CSS classes and assign those.

NB: as mentioned in comments, the order of the messages is no longer random.

Comment: where would I input the numbers that influence the delays then? I don't know javascript at all sorry.

Comment: One other thing is that it's randomly grabbing messages. I realized now that that's no good. It should actually just go through them in a normal 1,2,3,4,5... set sequence. not sure how that could be changed?

Comment: You have in your code the variable  `duration` which you gave the value 12000. So just modify it to your liking. It is one number, not several numbers. As you requested, those are random. I just made that randomness a bit dependent on `duration`. For the other question: I have altered the code so it takes the messages in sequence. But, please, if you have new questions, ask a new question via the proper way, not via comments.